# ImageView clickable, Webview and php

Tags: android, webview

I'm using Java with Android Studio and I reached a Goal.
1.ImageView clickable
2.Webview
3.PHP returning info about my personnal network
local weather and computer cpu usage for a specific ip address

in the webview.

Sure It would be awesome to only use HttpUrlConnection but it gived me
problem and this is why I decide webview was the answer.

in your AndroidManifest.xml, the usual:

in your activity_main.xml, insert the corresponding views.My Java code (MainActivity.java)
references to 3 ImageViews and the WebView.

here's the Java code:

```
// begin java code
package com.example.webview001;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;


@override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setTitle("Smarch Dashboard v.02");



ImageView mynetwork = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mynetwork);
ImageView mycpu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mycpu);
ImageView myweather = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myweather);
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

mynetwork.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@override
public void onClick(View view1) {
webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.18/backing/monitor/monitor.html");
}
});

mycpu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@override
public void onClick(View view2) {
webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.18/backing/monitor/mycpu.html");
}
});

myweather.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@override
public void onClick(View view3) {
webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.18/curltest/weather.php");
}
});
}
}
// end java code
```

Any suggestions, advises would be appreciated
Thanks and regards

Comment: and waht is the problem, where is the question?

Comment: Provide complete details of your problem.